# django, gravatar - add_to_builtins('gravatar.gravatar') causes crash on page load

Tags: django, gravatar

add_to_builtins('gravatar.gravatar')

- is being used in my settings.py file, and it causes a crash on page load with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 283, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 68, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 272, in **call**
>       response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 169, in get_response
>       response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
>       return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
>       html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 128, in get_traceback_html
>       t = Template(TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE, name='Technical 500 template')
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 108, in **init**
>       self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 135, in compile_string
>       parser = parser_class(lexer.tokenize())
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 34, in **init**
>       super(DebugParser, self).**init**(lexer)
>
> File "C:\development\python\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in **init**
>       print lib.tags
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tags'

If i don't have any issue with using gravatar if i don't use the add_to_builtins functionality - that is, with plain old load tags in my views. I'm just using it a fair bit, so thought i might make use of the add_to_builtins functionality.

From the looks of things, the imported version crashes because the `import_library(module)` for gravatar.gravatar returns None (i know this because i printed out that line, and it returns None)  - what is wrong with what i've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh gravatar.

Ok, so i was *all* wrong in how to import this using the add_to_builtins - what i needed to do was:

```
add_to_builtins('gravatar.templatetags.gravatar')
```

i'm unsure as to *why*, but that works a treat. Now i don't need to have any messy "load" statements, and i can happily call

```
{% gravatar story.user 40 %}
```

from any of my templates. yay!